# Return first character of string in NSArray for UIPickerView didSelectRow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, nsarray, uipickerview

I have a `UIPickerView` which returns an `NSArray` with 4 `strings`. When the user scrolls the `UIPickerView`, a `UITextField` gets updated with the selected row. I would like to return the first character of each `string` in the `NSArray` and update the `UITextField` with that character.

As you can see from my code, I have tried to achieve this functionality by using `self.noiseLevelArray = [noiseArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];`, which I found on a few different stack overflow questions.

Here is the code for the picker:

```
// Noise picker
self.noisePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
[noisePicker setDataSource:self];
[noisePicker setDelegate:self];
self.noiseArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"4: Extreme Noise (Impossible)", @"3: Very Noisy (Loud Shouting)", @"2: Noisy (Shouting)", @"1: Not Noisy (Normally)", nil];
//self.noiseLevelArray = [noiseArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

// Call noisePicker method
[self noisePickerTextField];
```

Here is the code for my picker:

```
// Picker components
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [noiseArray count];
    //return [noiseLevelArray count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [noiseArray objectAtIndex:row];
    //return [noiseLevelArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSString *noiseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", [noiseArray objectAtIndex:row]];
    //NSString *noiseString = [noiseLevelArray objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([self.empNoise1 isFirstResponder]) {
        self.empNoise1.text = noiseString;
    }
    else if ([self.empNoise2 isFirstResponder]) {
        self.empNoise2.text = noiseString;
    }
...
```

As you can see, the `UITextField` gets updated with the full `string` of whichever row is selected in the `UIPickerView`. I would like it to still display the full `string`, but update the `UITextField` with the first character only (in this case `1, 2, 3, or 4`). Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSString *noiseString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@", [[noiseArray objectAtIndex:row] substringToIndex:1]];
    //NSString *noiseString = [noiseLevelArray objectAtIndex:0];
    if ([self.empNoise1 isFirstResponder]) {
        self.empNoise1.text = noiseString;
    }
    else if ([self.empNoise2 isFirstResponder]) {
        self.empNoise2.text = noiseString;
    }
}
```

Try this. It uses the following method:

```
NSString * firstLetter = [word substringToIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.. `

```
self.empNoise1.text = [noiseString substringToIndex:1];`
```

**Returns a new string containing the characters of the receiver up to, but not including, the one at a given index.**

[Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#jumpTo_133)

Comment: This is just what I needed, thanks! Unfortunately I can't accept both answers, and you posted almost exactly the same time as "Merlea Dan", but I have up-voted your answer :)

Comment: No problem.  Credit to Merlea Dan for a more fulsome answer, and to @karthikeyan for editing mine to 'show my workings'.